# How do I show all of inner DIVs using nested JQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This my code, the first selector is for when i click on a div that has an id of # and the inner selector is an inner div that has the id of "popup-#" **my question is how do I show just the current inner div because currently when I click, all of the inner divs on the page are showing and hiding**. Side note these divs are generated through php and so they have values starting at 1 and increasing. Also another questions, **what is a better way to write the inner div selector to show instead of using .filter for show and hide ?** I couldn't find a way to use "this" for the inner selector.

ex. When I click on one of my outer divs that has an ID of "1" the inner div of "popup-1" should show and not all the others.

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return this.id.match(/^\d+$/);
}).click(function() {
    if($('div').filter(function () {
            return this.id.match(/popup-\d+$/);
        }).css('display') == 'none'
    ) {
        $('div').filter(function () {
            return this.id.match(/popup-\d+$/);
        }).show();  
    } else {
        $('div').filter(function () {
            return this.id.match(/popup-\d+$/);
        }).hide();
    };  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="test-style" id="1">
    <div class="inner-test" id="popup-1" style="display: none">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test-style" id="2">
    <div class="inner-test" id="popup-2" style="display: none">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can  include example `html` ?

Comment: A code snippet or jsfiddle would help

Comment: updated post with html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the class instead of filtering on the ID. Then you need to get the ID of the element you clicked on, and concatenate that with the `popup-` prefix to get the ID of the element you want to show.

```js
$(".test-style").click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  $(".inner-test").hide();
  $("#popup-" + id).show();
});
```

```css
.test-style {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.inner-test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-style" id="1">
  <div class="inner-test" id="popup-1" style="display: none">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test-style" id="2">
  <div class="inner-test" id="popup-2" style="display: none">
  </div>
</div>
```

But since the DIV you want to show is always inside the DIV you click on, you don't even need the IDs. Just do:

```
$(".test-style").click(function() {
  $(".inner-test").hide();
  $(this).find(".inner-test").show();
});
```

Comment: This is just a personal consideration: wouldn't it be simpler to use find(".inner-test") instead of using the id?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter

```
this.id.match(/popup-\d+$/)
```

matches all inner elements in the document, because of the general `'div'` selector.

Instead of

```
if($('div').filter(function () {
```

try

```
if($(this).filter(function () {
```

to filter on children of clicked element only.